# Script for .SAT (ACIS) files manipulation

Tags: scripting, 3d, cad, file-manipulation, sat

I need to make a script for ACIS files manipulation, for example:

I have 1 SAT file exported from a CAD software with a 3D Model, and i want to create a script in some language (php, python, etc.. even .BAT if it works) that opens the SAT file delete all the components inside my 3D model. I just want the outside of the 3D model.

There is some way to do this? becuase i look to the SAT file and it's an ammount of text lines, maybe with a RFC and some tricky tools i can do this..

Any ideia?

Best Regards,
Pedro Vieira

Comment: The Wikipedia article for [ACIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACIS#External_links) has a link to the file format spec.

There is a PDF document and an example: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/sat/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pedro,
SAT is the proprietary format of the ACIS solid modeling kernel which is provided by [Spatial Corp](http://www.spatial.com).

It is a commercial 3D geometry modeling toolkit.

I do not believe you'll find a reliable way of doing what you're asking without licensing the toolkit.

Full disclosure- I work for Spatial.

If you can export a STEP file, it is an open format which is documented and quite reliable. Wikipedia has an article on STEP [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_10303-21).

-Brad

Answer (score 0):

If you has an ACIS distribution, it has a tool that allows you processing SAT files with a LISP script. I worked with ACIS several years ago, and I remember I could find SAT file format description (not very detailed) in the net. Probably there are tools that can work with SAT besides ACIS, but they are usually not very powerful. I think ODA Teigha library also can do a trick or another with SAT files, if you get your hands on it. Mastering SAT format processing yourself is probably not a best choice.